# Forcing index in MySQL does not seem to work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an SQL query that gets total attendance for services during a specific time frame.

I've got my query working, but for some reason it's doing a full table scan on a single table and not using a index (even when I used `FORCE INDEX`).

Here's a live sample of [my schema, query and output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9aa/6).

After the query is run you'll see that the `st` has the possible key of `service_id` but instead it does a full table scan (`ALL`).

I've  been playing around using `FORCE INDEX` on different table joins but cannot seem to make all joined tables use the correct index. Changing one index affects another index. I presume I have either set-up an index wrong or have totally missed something obvious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

One idea. I don't think your query is doing what you think it's doing.

It looks to me like you've got parens where there shouldn't be any.
Here:

```
  WHERE st.time BETWEEN('2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03') AND
        st.deleted = 0
```

I think MySQL is evaluating whats inside the parens...

```
    ('2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03')
```

And that evaluates to TRUE, which is returned as integer value `1`. So what you have is really equivalent to:

```
  WHERE st.time BETWEEN 1 AND st.deleted = 0
```

There's an order of precedence... either the equality comparison or the `AND` (which is considered part of the `BETWEEN` comparison) is going to be evaluated first. It's going to be equivalent to either:

```
  WHERE ( st.time BETWEEN 1 AND st.deleted ) = 0
```

-or-

```
  WHERE st.time BETWEEN 1 AND ( st.deleted = 0 )
```

I'd need to run some tests to figure out which it's doing. But in either case, it's not likely either way is what you expect, or what you really want.  MySQL can't make use of the index with a leading column of `time` for a range scan, because it needs the value of the `deleted` column before that.

I suggest you fix your query before you do any more work on getting to use an index.

I'm thinking what you want is something like this:

```
  WHERE st.time BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
    AND st.deleted = 0
```

---

For comparison, consider the return from these statements:

```
SELECT '2016-01-02' BETWEEN ('2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03') AND 1=1  --> 0

SELECT '2016-01-02' BETWEEN  '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'  AND 1=1  --> 1

SELECT '2016-01-02' BETWEEN ('2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03')  --> syntax error
```

Comment: You're totally right! I needs to be `(st.time BETWEEN'2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03')`! I've now rectified that issue http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9aa/6 It is however still doing a full table scan. Is it possible to make the `services_times` table use the `service_id` index even though it's not in the `WHERE`? I use `st.service_id` within a `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, you reference `st.service_id` in a predicate, but that's being compared to `s.id`. And MySQL is electing to do an index lookup on `s.id`. The execution plan looked right to me.  If you want an index used on for `service_times`, the optimal index is likely a covering index `... ON service_times (\`time\`,\`deleted\`,\`service_id\`)`. The addition of covering indexes on the other tables would also likely be beneficial. (EXPLAIN will show "Using index" which means that the query is satisfied from the index without visiting pages in the underlying table.

Comment: It's not reasonable for MySQL to use an index `ON service_times   (service_id)` to satisfy your query, because MySQL still has to go to the rows in the underlying table, in order to satisfy the predicates in the WHERE clause, and to get the `id` value so it can do the join to `sa`. It might be possible to "force" MySQL to use index, but you'd need to allow MySQL to use a different join order, and different access paths to the other tables i.e. removing the `FORCE INDEX` for the other tables.

Comment: The question at the forefront of my mind is "Why do you want MySQL to use that index?" What are you attempting to achieve? What's the point?